# Change cells value in Datatables in selected rows only - Prime For Record Action

Tags: datatables

I m trying to target some cells values only in selected row or rows.
I have tried a code as explained in the following snippets but it keeps targeting the first row, not the selected one,

Please excuse me as the checkbox in the table is not showing up, you can still use multiselect by pressing shift and clicking the place of the checkbox

```js
var tablenest = $('#RegSrc').DataTable({
  select: true,
  "bPaginate": false,
  "bFilter": false,
  responsive: true,
  deferRender: true,
  "processing": true,
  "serverSide": false,
  bAutoWidth: true,
  data: [{
    "RecID": 2383,
    "PtFilenum": 15090248,
    "PrtFilenum": 13090701,
    "Fullname": " sadden ",
    "PrtStatus": 1
  }, {
    "RecID": 2384,
    "PtFilenum": 15090248,
    "PrtFilenum": 15120996,
    "Fullname": "marwam mohmmad saleem",
    "PrtStatus": 1
  }, {
    "RecID": 2385,
    "PtFilenum": 15090248,
    "PrtFilenum": 170227111,
    "Fullname": "asd dsf a",
    "PrtStatus": 1
  }],
  order: [2, 'asc'],
  keys: {
    columns: ':not(:first-child)',
    keys: [9]
  },
  columns: [{ // Checkbox select column
      data: null,
      defaultContent: '',
      className: 'select-checkbox',
      orderable: false,
      "width": "1%"
    },
    {
      "width": "50%",
      data: "RecID",
      "visible": false
    },
    {
      "width": "50%",
      data: "PtFilenum",
      "visible": false
    },
    {
      "width": "10%",
      data: "PrtFilenum"
    },
    {
      "width": "40%",
      data: "Fullname"
    },
    {
      "width": "10%",
      data: "PrtStatus",
      render: function(data, type, row) {
        if (type === 'display') {
          if (data == 1) {
            return 'Partners';
          } else {
            return 'Not Partners';
          }
        }
        return data;
      },
      className: "dt-body-center"
    },
    {
      "width": "10%",
      data: [],
      defaultContent: 'update',
       orderable: false,
      className: "dt-body-center",
       "visible": true
    },
  ],

});

$("#btn1").click(function() {
  tablenest.rows({
    selected: true
  }).every(function(rowIdx, tableLoop, rowLoop) {
    tablenest.row(this).cell(rowIdx, 6).data("delete")
    var row = tablenest.row( this ).node();
    $(row).addClass('highlight');

  });
  return false;
})
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>



<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/jqc-1.12.4/moment-2.18.1/dt-1.10.15/b-1.3.1/se-1.2.2/datatables.min.js"></script>



<button id="btn1" class="btn btn-primary">Mark For Delete</button>

<table id="RegSrc" class="table table-bordered table-striped table-condensed mb-none display responsive nowrap" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th><b>RecID</b></th>
      <th><b>Patient File Number</b></th>
      <th><b>Partner File Number</b></th>
      <th><b>Patient Name</b></th>
      <th><b>Status</b></th>
      <th><b></b></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bingo,

```
 PrtTbl.rows({ selected: true }).every(function (rowIdx, tableLoop, rowLoop) {
                               PrtTbl.row(this).cell(rowIdx,2).data("").draw()
                               PrtTbl.row(this).cell(rowIdx, 3).data("").draw()
                           });
```

I edited the example above